# $\int_{\Omega}a(t)\, d\mu(t)=\text{const}\Rightarrow a\equiv\text{const}$?

Tags: integration

As the title already says I am wondering if

> $\int_{\Omega}a(t)\, d\mu(t)=\text{const}\Rightarrow a\equiv\text{const}$, whereat $\mu$ is a normalized measure on $\Omega$

Do not know exactly how to show that.

Comment: $\int_{\Omega}a(t)\, d\mu(t)$ is always a constant, wether $a$ is constant or not.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $\mu$ is a normalized measure on $\Omega$.

Comment: The integral of a function is a number. What does $\int_{\Omega}a(t)\, d\mu(t)$ depend on?