# Why is the constant here equal to $a$?

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $(\Omega,R)$ denote a flow, where $\Omega$ is compact metric space and $\gamma$ is a normalized measure on $\Omega$.

I have problems to understand the following passage in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039678900773, page 26, Line (5):

> > Since the flow $(\Omega,R)$ is uniquely ergodic, one has, for each $\omega_0\in\Omega$,
> >     $$
> > \lim_{\lvert t\rvert\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_0^ta(\omega_0\cdot s)\, ds=\int_{\Omega}a(\omega)\, d\gamma(\omega)=\text{const}\equiv a.
> > $$

The first equation is just a property that follows from the ergodicity of the flow.

But I do not understandwhy the constant is equal to $a$.

Or is it just a not so good notation to call the constant $a$ (because the function in the integrand is already called $a$?)

With other words: Are the function in the integrand and the constant the same?

Comment: My immediate reading would be that they're defining the letter $a$ to mean whatever constant the integral comes out to. (That's one of the multitude of possible meanings for $\equiv$).

Comment: So this $a$ is not the function $a$?

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: @mathfemi: Correct, or at least my first guess for making sense of the text would be this. If what follows seems to be nonsense under that assumption, it's back to the drawing board.

Comment: I will add the source of it it.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986032/int-omegaat-d-mut-textconst-rightarrow-a-equiv-textconst?

Comment: Sorry, in that linked question I asked it wrong.